# Octave: How to cirumvent the "imresize: IM must be a grayscale or RGB image" error?

Tags: image, matlab, octave, image-resizing

This is an [active bug](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/octave-bug-tracker/2014-12/msg00185.html) in Octave:

```
error: imresize: IM must be a grayscale or RGB image.
```

I can't seem to find a way around this error. Is there any code that is to be added before this statement for it to function as it does in MATLAB?

**UPDATE**

Code from [active bug](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/octave-bug-tracker/2014-12/msg00185.html):

```
In = ones(6,6);
In(3,3) = 2;
Out = imresize (In, 2);
```

Version:

- OS-X 10.9.4
- Octave-4.0.3 (direct install [from SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/octave/files/Octave%20MacOSX%20Binary/2016-07-11-binary-octave-4.0.3/octave_gui_403_appleblas.dmg/download))

Comment: What's your problem here? The bug you've linked is already fixed https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?43846 on the repo. Show some code what you are tryint to do? Do you have neagtive values in your image?

Comment: Did you read documentation - https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Representing-Images.html? For matrix of double value of pixel must be in range 0...1

Comment: @SergV: I'm clear with the details you've provided. Isn't my question legitimate? I'm asking for a solution to a known problem without a well-known solution. (Why the downvote?) I have a code which works well in MATLAB and not with Octave and this line seems to be the only problem.

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac the downvotes are because you haven't tried even the bare minimum to solve it (or you havent shown that you tried)

Comment: @AnderBiguri: I tried to find the solution all over the internet only to find bug reports. Some of such reports have `solved` in them; some others have been set `invalid`. However, none of which provides a feasible solution to my problem.

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac why don't you just download the fixed imresize.m and replace it in your Installation?

Comment: @Andy: Thank you so much, your suggestion solved my problem.

Comment: image 2.6.0 has been released this night which should solve your issue

Comment: @Andy: I'm getting a `configure: error: *** A compiler with support for C++11 is required`, and I'm not able to find a viable solution around this. Could you please give a suggestion to install it? (OS-X 10.9)

Comment: Oh, OSX... it depends if using fink, macports, homebrew but you aren't going to tell how you've installed Octave and which version it is

Comment: @Andy: I've provided the additional information in the post just now. I previously used MacPorts installation of Octave 3.8.0. After your suggestion, I did a fresh install of Octave 4.0.3 from SourceForge (but retained the MacPorts install as well) to satisfy `image-2.6.0`'s requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The pixels of grayimage in octave must be in [0..1] range. You can scale amplitude of your matrix to satisfy this criterion:

```
In = ones(6,6);
In(3,3) = -1;

minIn=min(In(:)); 
maxIn=max(In(:)); 
In1=(In-minIn)/(maxIn - minIn);
Out = imresize (In1, 2);
Out1=Out*(maxIn-minIn) + minIn;
```

Answer (score 0):

I havent tested it, but I assume that:

```
In = ones(6,6);
In(3,3) = -1;

minIn=min(In(:)); % do this
In=In-minIn;      % do this - now In(3,3)=0!

Out = imresize (In, 2);

Out=Out+minIn;    % do this
```

Will do the job

Comment: Sadly, I'm getting the same error. I'm using the version Octave-v3.8. Do you think its time for me to update to fix this?

Comment: @Ander Biguri. You must change sign on minIn in your script. So "In=In+minIn;  " change to "In=In-minIn;". And   "Out=Out-minIn;" to Out=Out+minIn;

Comment: @SergV: That's just the problem, even the given code doesn't seem to work with your changes.

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac perhaps it's time to create a mcve?http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Without showing your code or describing what you are trying to do it's pure guessing...

Comment: Sorry, @SergV, but your edited code still shows the same error. I've just verified the same problem with Octave-4.0.2 too.

Answer (score 0):

Exending @Andy's comments, the `imresize.m` MATLAB file can be placed in the directory of operation. This would execute the code as in MATLAB and would not raise the error like in the Octave's implementation.

The code can be taken from [this location](https://svn.ecdf.ed.ac.uk/repo/ph/IGM/matlab/generic/graphics/img/imresize.m).

Comment: I never suggested to get imresize.m from Matlab. Have a look at their license. You aren't allowed to use this file outside of Matlab even if you pay for it. I said you should get the fixed imresize.m from the Octave-forge image package here: http://hg.code.sf.net/p/octave/image/file/17ed4752a081/inst/imresize.m (click on raw and download file)

Comment: @Andy I just tried out the code in your link, an error is raised stating `'isimage' undefined near line 65 column 13`.